# Declaring multiple artifactId under one groupId in a pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

I'm declaring quite a few dependencies within one package in a Maven pom.xml, and the document is getting very long and difficult to maintain as is, even without a separate dependency block for each referenced artifact. Instead of doing this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test.foo</groupId>
        <artifactId>bar1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test.foo</groupId>
        <artifactId>bar2</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test.foo</groupId>
        <artifactId>bar3</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Is it possible (and I'd be willing to work with a plugin, if necessary) to do something like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test.foo</groupId>
        <artifactId>bar1</artifactId>
        <artifactId>bar2</artifactId>
        <artifactId>bar3</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[No](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies). But if you own those dependencies (I assume from your code that you do) you can have a module aggregating all those dependencies, then you can depend on that module. Or if working in a multi module project you can create a parent pom to define the dependencies from your project so you don't repeat it everywhere.